# Cakephp sanitizing and special characters

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding

i'm using sanitize::paranoid on a string but i need to exclude a few special characters but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$content=sanitize::paranoid($content,array('à',' '));
```

I've changed the encoding of my file from ansi to utf8 but cakephp doesn't really like it so i need to find another way.

That array should contain the list of characters to exclude from sanitization, but it keep removing the "à" and i want those character in the final string.

Comment: which Cake Version are you using..?

Comment: Do you have PCRE with unicode support?

Comment: @BarryChapman it's a cms, we can't make assumptions on the server configuration

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of these parsing/sanitization classes rely heavily on regular expressions. You may want to check.

Comment: Is the datasource where $content gets it's data utf8 as well? And have you set the UTF8 encoding var in app/Config/Database.php (if coming from a DB)?

Comment: @Oldskool the whole system works with utf8. data come from a form synced with ajax. printing the variable before sanitizing it has the "à" but after it get removed because it doesn't exclude the right char from the paranoid command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sanitize:paranoid` is a simple `preg_replace` (`$allow` is just additional characters, escaped):

```
preg_replace("/[^{$allow}a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $string);
```

As you can see, `paranoid` is quite paranoid... doesn't accept non-ascii letters by default.

The file where you had the `à` was probably saved in another encoding (working on windows?)

Anyway, if you want you can write a better filter by using `/[^\p{L}]/u`, which excludes letters in any lanaguage.

Comment: thank you, this worked almost perfectly but it replaces blank spaces too. i'm not really good with regex, how can i exclude blank spaces too?

Comment: add a space before the `]`, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Sanitize::paranoid function:

```
cleaned = preg_replace("/[^{$allow}a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $string);
```

Because your character (à) is not in this range it will not be returned. 
If you're using Cake 2.x you can override the Sanitize class in your app folder 
and replace all occurrences of:

```
a-zA-Z0-9
```

with:

```
\w
```

This should return the accented character (it does for me). You can also look at the 
[multibyte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) if you like but that might be a problem if you're building a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

it must be some special encoding problems that cakephp paranoid doesnt know

```
Sanitize::paranoid($badString, array(' ', '@')); @ is the allowed char
```

it should be working. i tried this example myself